# How to prove the expression $|a|/|1+a^2|$ has an upper bound 1?

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

[image]

From this lecture https://www.udemy.com/course/advanced-calculusreal-analysis-with-the-math-sorcerer/learn/lecture/15077264#overview

It looks like the lecturer made a mistake in the proof. It is hard to Google up this sequence, I was unable to find it anywhere.

Comment: Probably, it is either meant to be $|a| \leq 1$, or assume $a$ is positive w.l.o.g.

Comment: "sequence"?  What sequence?  There is no sequence here...

Comment: First clause of the line in which you circle something: "If $a \leq 1$" should be "If $|a| \leq 1$".  Same edit to the beginning of the next line.  The expression $\frac{|a|}{|1+a^2|}$ is even in $a$, so considering $a < 0$ at all is redundant.

Comment: @EricTowers sorry my fault

Comment: Note that the inequality between geometric and arithmetic mean shows gives the better upper bound $|a|/|1+a^2| \le 1/2$, which is sharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming $a\in\mathbb{R}$. If it is not the case, please let me know.

By the AM-GM inequality we know that
$$\sqrt{1\cdot a^{2}}\leq \frac{1+a^{2}}{2}$$
So
$$
\sqrt{a^{2}}<1+a^{2}\implies \left|a\right|<1+a^{2}
$$
since $1+a^{2}>0$ then $\left|a\right|<\left|1+a^{2}\right|$, so $1$ is an upper bound on $\frac{\left|a\right|}{\left|1+a^{2}\right|}$